# Why won't the JButtons, JLabels and JTextFields be displayed?

Tags: java, swing

This code enables an employee to log in to the coffee shop system. I admit I have a lot of unneeded code. My problem is that when I run the program just the image is displayed above and no JButtons, JLabels or JTextFields.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class login extends JFrame {



public void CreateFrame() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome");


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1000,1000));
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
    imagePanel.show();

    panel.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);



}

public static void main(String... args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new login().CreateFrame();
            }
        });

    } 
}

class GUI extends JFrame{

private JButton buttonLogin;
private JButton buttonNewUser;
private JLabel iUsername;
private JLabel iPassword;
private JTextField userField;
private JPasswordField passField;
public void createGUI(){

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
    loginPanel.setOpaque(false);
    loginPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,3,3));



    iUsername = new JLabel("Username ");
    iUsername.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    userField = new JTextField(10);
    iPassword = new JLabel("Password ");
    iPassword.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    passField = new JPasswordField(10);
    buttonLogin = new JButton("Login");
    buttonNewUser = new JButton("New User");



    loginPanel.add(iUsername);
    loginPanel.add(iPassword);
    loginPanel.add(userField);
    loginPanel.add(passField);
    loginPanel.add(buttonLogin);
    loginPanel.add(buttonNewUser);

    add(loginPanel);

    pack();

    Writer writer = null;
    File check = new File("userPass.txt");
    if(check.exists()){

        //Checks if the file exists. will not add anything if the file does exist.
    }else{
        try{
                File texting = new File("userPass.txt");
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(texting));
                writer.write("message");
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }




    buttonLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                File file = new File("userPass.txt");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);;
                String line = null;
                FileWriter filewrite = new FileWriter(file, true);

                String usertxt = " ";
                String passtxt = " ";
                String puname = userField.getText();
                String ppaswd = passField.getText();


                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    usertxt = scan.nextLine();
                    passtxt = scan.nextLine();
                }




                if(puname.equals(usertxt) && ppaswd.equals(passtxt)) {
                    MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
                    dispose();
                } 
                else if(puname.equals("") && ppaswd.equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please insert Username and Password");
                }
                else {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Username / Password");
                    userField.setText("");
                    passField.setText("");
                    userField.requestFocus();
                }
            } catch (IOException d) {
                d.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    buttonNewUser.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            NewUser user = new NewUser();
            dispose();
        }
    });


}

}




  class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

  private BufferedImage image;

  public ImagePanel(){
      setOpaque(true);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,5));
      try
      {
          image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ8F5S_KK7uelpM5qdQXuaL1r09SS484R3-gLYArOp7Bom-LTYTT8Kjaiw"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      GUI show = new GUI();
      show.createGUI();
    }


    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return (new Dimension(430, 300));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,this);
   }
}
```

Comment: Code for login and new menu ??

Comment: Your code is complete mess. Suggest you start from scratch. First create app that just show empty frame. Look at it until you understand every bit of code. Then add image. Look again. Then add one button that does nothing. repeat until you finish. You code shows that you do not understand what you write. I don't try to offend you but you need to learn not just copy paste random code from internet but **understand** what it does.

Comment: the thing is that I coded a login, but the problem arose when I needed to make a background. there is when i got confused

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you have a class `login` (which is a `JFrame`, but never used as one). This login class creates a new generic "Welcome" `JFrame` with the `ImagePanel` in it. The ImagePanel calls `GUI.createGUI()` (which creates another JFrame, but doesn't show it) and then does absolutely nothing with it, thus it is immediately lost.

There are way to many JFrames in your code. One should be enough, perhaps two. But you got three: login, gui, and a simple new JFrame().

Comment: @lfarr if you created another frame and did not show it , then add `setVisible(true)` in that `JFrame`